# file reading error in C++

Tags: c++, file

I have a very simple code, but I am not able to find out the mistake. 
task: I want to read the text file which contains float/double values. Text file looks like below:

--datalog.txt--

```
3.000315
3.000944
3.001572
3.002199
3.002829
3.003457
3.004085
3.004714
3.005342
3.005970
3.006599
3.007227
3.007855
3.008483
3.009112
3.009740
3.010368
3.010997
```

code looks like this

--dummy_c++.cpp--

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h> //for exit()function
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream infile;
  double val;

  infile.open("datalog");

  for (int i=0; i<=20; i++)
    {
      if(infile >> val){
    cout << val << endl;
      } else {
    cout << "end of file" << endl;
      }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
end of file
end of file
end of file
end of file
end of file
end of file
end of file
end of file
end of file
end of file
end of file
end of file
end of file
end of file
end of file
end of file
end of file
end of file
end of file
end of file
end of file
```

where as I expect it will print same as that of datalog.txt file.

could you please help me to locate the mistake ?

thanks, 
Milind.

Comment: You say the file is called `datalog.txt`, but the file name you pass to  `infile.open` is `"datalog"`. Which way is it? Before reading from the file, check that `open()` actually succeeds.

Comment: Your code is likely trying to open a non existing file. When you do this, the `failbit` of the `fstream` is set, which means the `boolean` evaluation of the stream in your `if-statement` always evaluates to `false`, which is why the `'end of file' else-statement` is reached in each iteration. Also you should not be iterating a specific number of times, but rather til a specific number of times, OR till the end of the file has been reached (in the case, that you really do wants to reach a specific number of lines). Also I suggest you test if the file is really opened successfully.

Comment: May I suggest that you use a while (!EOF) instead of a for loop with a variable (20)? Your main problem is what everyone else has mentioned with your file name.

Comment: oh....I changed the file name while passing in to Infile.open as datalog.txt and now the program works fine. thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

If your file is really called `datalog.txt` you should make sure you try to open that:

```
infile.open("datalog.txt");
//                  ^^^^^^
```

The exe will look for it in the current directory if you don't fully path it.

Answer (score 2):

You've specified the wrong file to open; use:

```
infile.open("datalog.txt");
```

You can guard against attempting to use unopened files, with a simple test:

```
infile.open("datalog.txt");
if (infile) {
    // Use the file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you simply mispelled the file name? You say the file is called "datalog.txt" but in the code you open "datalog".

Answer (score 0):

Use the proper file name :-) It works for me, then. The 'datalog' file has only 18 lines, not twenty, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the file name is `"datalog.txt"`. In the code you are using `"datalog"`.
Also always check the stream after using it, to be sure that the file was correctly opened:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile;
    double val;

    infile.open("dalatog.txt");

    if( infile )
    {
        for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; ++i)
        {
            if(infile >> val)
                std::cout << val << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "end of file" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << "The file was not correctly oppened" << std::endl;
}
```

In addition, its better to use a while loop instead of a for loop which checks for the EOF:

```
while( infile >> val )
{
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps using a std::getline() function would be better

Comment: Why? OP is reading floating-point values, no strings. What OP does is the best option. Your option (Read the complete line as a string and parse that string to get the float), is a mess, and has no sense at all.